# Apache PHP-FPM "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

Just as a note to self, and might be helpful to others...

My Apache `error_log` contained the error:

- Software caused connection abort
- Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)

For example:

```
[Mon Sep 07 12:56:24.267462 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13938:tid 140607124641236] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 1.1.1.1:9060] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: https://example.com/path/
```

And the Apache `access_log` contained:

```
1.1.1.1 - - [2020-09-07 12:56:17] [-] "POST /path/ HTTP/2.0" 400 308 "https://example.com/path/" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
```

Note the HTTP status of `400 Bad Request`, and it happened 7 seconds later.

Also, where it's being processed in PHP, I use `register_shutdown_function` to create my own log file, which details every request - including the UserID, the `http_response_code()` (in this case `200`), how long the request took to process (`0.031` seconds), and when it happened (the later time, `12:56:17`).

This is with Apache/2.4.29 and PHP-FPM 7.2

Comment: I don't know who/why this got a -1... this is an issue with no search results for it, and it should help someone who experiences the same issue... is it because I've provided the correct, and not obvious answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened when the user was part way uploading a file, and canceled it.

The partial file is still passed to PHP-FPM, and the PHP script still runs.

PHP sets `$_FILES['name']['error'] === 3`, to indicate the file has been partially uploaded; so, in my script, I returned a HTML page with an error message about the incomplete file (hence the `200` response in my logs).

I assume the `Software caused connection abort` and `Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)` is describing how this HTML is not being returned to the client/browser.

Comment: i had the same issue today, but i check `$_FILES['name']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK` before executing anything. and still got the error in my log files?
As per you're assumption is this a client side related issue or something i need to fix?

Comment: I got my system to handle it gracefully (e.g. if it's an incomplete upload, return a normal web page that shows an error message, and re-shows the form for them to try again)... but ultimately it's a client side issue, they started the upload and cancelled it, they probably won't see the error, but I thought I'd still return it anyway (just in case).